# Javascript pdf parser and events

Tags: javascript, pdf

Is there a way to set events on pdf elements (say text, images, ...) while a pdf is loaded in an html page ?

For example: click on a sentence and alert the full sentence in a a parent frame

Answer (score 0):

You could try a pdf api, check out [Mozilla pdf](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), you might be able to manipulate the canvas element. the people working on it are active , so you can ask them for help after you have tried the api.

Comment: Do you know a way to contact them here in stackoverflow, as this request will be logged here ?

Comment: no sorry , that only way I can think of is getting asking them on github and you can share their response here